# Php Mysql, article Tags for custom CMS

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a small self made CMS for a Blog.
Currently I have simple MySql database set up like this:

[image: Database_diagram]

For a main page, I have a index.php which is supposed to fetch all the articles and print out their name, date, excerpt and all the tags this article has. Now the problem is I have no idea on how to print out all the tags of all articles, under each of them.

The articles are pulled and printed using a simple mysqli:

```
  $sql = "SELECT id, nazwa, data, wstep, imgs, zdj
  FROM art WHERE id BETWEEN $end AND $start ORDER BY id desc;";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$result){
  echo "Problem\n";
  echo "Kod problemu: ". mysqli_error($link);
  exit;
}

...

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $id = $row['id'];
//Barfing out all the content 
}
```

I would like to have a second query, inside that fetch assoc, but when I do that, the website fails to load posts completely.
Is there another, good way of doing this?

Comment: wow ... using `between` with `$end` and `$start`. that's a new one...

Comment: @hummingBird For problems in excess of the speed of light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not modifying your query to include tags in line with articles? I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but it would be simple enough to concatenate it w/ commas:

```
SELECT 
   a.id, 
   a.nazwa, 
   a.data, 
   a.wstep, 
   a.imgs, 
   a.zdj,
   GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) all_tags
FROM 
   art a INNER JOIN tagarts ta ON a.id = ta.id INNER JOIN tags t ON t.idt = ta.idt
 WHERE id BETWEEN $end AND $start
 GROUP BY a.id
 ORDER BY a.id desc;
```

Then do a split in PHP and voila!

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
   foreach(explode(',', $row['all_tags']) as $tag) {
      echo '<a href="somepath/tags?t={$tag}">{$tag}</a>';
   }
}
```

This would be much more preferable than using some query instead of that inner `foreach`.

In any case, your remark that everything breaks when you actually *try* doing these queries in a loop probably means that you simply have some issues with your code. Still, even if it worked, it would work slow.

But you might actually need something completely different, in which case don't kill me but someone else.

Comment: Not good for me. The tags should be clickable, and lead to a specified href

Comment: Not sure I get you... Whether or not something is clickable shouldn't be something you're pulling from db. Are you saying I god the _direction_ wrong?

Comment: if I get it by Concat, it will only print out a string made out of the elements inside. I'd like it to be a normal array which I could print out like
_<a href="index.php?tag=<?php echo $row["tag"] ?>"><?php echo $row["tag"] ?></a>_

Comment: it's much better to parse tags then to do queries in a foreach. check my edit

Comment: Thanks for the php edit but still there is a problem with the mysql code. 
1)It only prints out one row of data
2) it prints out all of the tags, and not only tags contained by a certain art

Comment: It worked! The php required some tricking, eventually worked with:
`<?php
                  foreach(explode(',', $row['all_tags']) as $tag) {?>
                  <a href="somepath/tags?t=<?php echo $tag; ?>"><?php echo $tag; ?>  </a>  <?php } ?>`
Thank you very much!